# windows based PC freeze up after showing event ID 6013

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, event-viewer

I have a windows based PC that randomly freezes up. when I checked event log, I figured out the latest log was at noon (12:00) after event log 6013.

[image]

Comment: Try checking scheduled tasks, virus scans, updates, etc. Try opening system monitor before it happens, sorting processes by cpu/disk utilisation to find the offending one.

Comment: check this help page from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504